# How to restrict url access with apache to certain IP?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm using a `apache2` on ubuntu, in front of a `tomcat8` webserver.
I want to restrict access to `localhost/manager` to only a specific ip address.

The server is in my internal network and has the ip `102.168.139.111`. I want to be able to access the `/manager` endpoint only from my local machine `192.168.128.222`, and from nowhere else.

But the following does not work and I'm always getting a `403 Permission denied`. Why?

`apache2.conf`:

```
<Location /manager/*>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Deny from  all
        Allow from 192.168.128.197
</Location>
```

With:

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Sidenote: taking the `<Location...>` out will allow access to my local IP as expected. So the server configuration in general seems to be fine. Just restricting does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an order of statements issue. The following works (on root path):

```
<Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 192.168.
</Location>
```